# Amount of information on Controller Method - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, dashboard

I am worried about the amount of information that is presented on a controller method for a dashboard view. Basically this dashboard view shows user informations and activity inside my application, but I think this is quickly turning into a mess, due to the amount of information being passed to the view.

```
@answered = answered.length
@asked = asked.length
@pending = pending.length
@favorited = favorited.length
@medal_gold = thanks_received(:awesome).length
@medal_silver = thanks_received(:great).length
@medal_bronze = thanks_received(:good).length
@notification_pending = question_users_not_seen(pending, current_user.user_notification.pending_last_seen).count
@notification_silver = question_users_not_seen(thanks_received(:great), current_user.user_notification.silver_last_seen).count
@notification_gold = question_users_not_seen(thanks_received(:awesome), current_user.user_notification.gold_last_seen).count
@notification_bronze = question_users_not_seen(thanks_received(:good), current_user.user_notification.bronze_last_seen).count
@notification_asked = question_users_not_seen(asked, current_user.user_notification.asked_last_seen).any?
@notification_answered = question_users_not_seen(answered, current_user.user_notification.answered_last_seen).any?
@notification_favorited = question_users_not_seen(favorited, current_user.user_notification.favorited_last_seen).any?
```

Is there a more elegantly way of writing all this information? I'm only worried about how the code looks, not so much about its performance.

Comment: You may want to use more helpers, or class methods on the models related to these values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be good occasion to use hashes. For example,

```
@attr_counts = {:answered => answered.length, :asked => asked.length, :pending => pending.length, :favorited => favorited.length}
@medal_lengths = {:gold => thanks_received(:awesome).length, :silver => thanks_received(:great).length, :bronze => thanks_received(:good).length}
```